# Register the print function

Tags: c, pointers, printf, glibc

I'm need to register the print function for print float's fract part xxx.yy -> yy

But but it's don't work as need. I think that this is a problem with pointer, but i can't understand where is a problem.

```
int  print_fr (FILE *stream,const struct printf_info *info
                        ,const void *const *args)
{
  char *buffer;
  const float ff = *((const float *) (args[0]));

  printf("%f\n", ff); // if 123.45 -> -107374184.000000

  double fract_part, int_part;
  fract_part = modf(ff, &int_part);
  int len = asprintf (&buffer, "%.0f",fract_part);

  if (len == -1) return -1;

  len = fprintf (stream, "%*s",
                  (info->left ? -info->width : info->width),
                  buffer);
  free (buffer);
  return len;
}

int  print_fr_arginfo (const struct printf_info *info, size_t n
                       ,int *argtypes)
{
   if (n > 0)
       argtypes[0] = PA_FLOAT;
     return 1;
}
```

main.c

```
 /* Register the print function */
 register_printf_function ('w', print_ff, print_ff_arginfo);

 printf("%w\n", 123.45); // result -0
```

Comment: (a) The code in the question defines `printf_fr` but passes `print_ff` to `register_printf_function`, and `printf_ff` is not defined. This code will not compile. When asking why code is not working, always include a correct [mcve]. (b) Do not reinterpret data using `*((const float *) (args[0]))`; this is not supported by the C standard. You could use `float ff; memcpy(&ff, args[0], sizeof ff);`. (c) `fract_part = modf(ff, &int_part);` sets `fract_part` to `.45f`, and then `asprintf (&buffer, "%.0f",fract_part)` formats it as “0”. You need to do more math to deal with the fraction part.

Comment: what are you doing, that the code needs to call some function to register that function?  What do you mean by 'register the function'?

Comment: @Eric Postpischil this is a missprint! thanks for the answer but unfortunately your code will not work too ( memcpy(&ff, args[0], sizeof ff); -> fract_part = modf(ff, &int_part); ->printf("%lf\n", fract_part) ) = -0.000000

Comment: @YaroslavRakhnenko: You seem to have missed the “(c)” separating issues in my comment. The code in (b) tells you how to reinterpret bits correctly. (c) tells you why your current code does not work.

Answer (score 0):

to just print the fractional part of a float value::

```
#include <math.h>  // floorf()
float integerNum = floorf( originalFloat );
float fractNum = originalFloat - integerNum;
printf( "%f\n", fractNum );
```

Comment: Thank you! but i need to use sprintf with my format, thats why i want to register  print function